# How to set more than one shared preference, without first creating xml

Tags: android

I am trying to setup more than one shared preference with this method.
This will successfully create one shared pref:

```
 static final String SUPPLIER_NUMBER = "";

   SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   savednumber = myPrefs.getString(SUPPLIER_NUMBER, "");

           SharedPreferences myPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs1.edit();
           prefsEditor.putString(SUPPLIER_NUMBER, telephonenumber);
           prefsEditor.commit();
```

This second example simply results in the second pref overriding the first....??? What am I missing here?

```
 static final String SUPPLIER_NUMBER = "";
 static final String SUPPLIER_COST = "";

       SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       savednumber = myPrefs.getString(SUPPLIER_NUMBER, "");
       savedcost = myPrefs.getString(SUPPLIER_COST, "");

               SharedPreferences myPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
               SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs1.edit();
               prefsEditor.putString(SUPPLIER_NUMBER, telephonenumber);
               prefsEditor.putString(SUPPLIER_COST, suppliercost);
               prefsEditor.commit();
```

I do not really want to create an xml file to get the prefs from.. I want it dynamically created, as I believe I am getting here, in the first example.. but I need to be able to add more than one preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your SUPPLIER_NUMBER and SUPPLIER_COST constants are equal (both are ""). Set them to different values and that should do the trick :)

```
 static final String SUPPLIER_NUMBER = "number";
 static final String SUPPLIER_COST = "cost";
```

Comment: Thank you.. i had a feeling it would be a stupid oversight by me.. i had initially thought that that space was reserved for the default value.. all works great now thanks.!